# How should I screw in an outlet if the backsplash hole is misaligned?

Tags: receptacle, backsplash

The image below shows that the outlet box is slightly misaligned with the hole in my backsplash. I am debating how I should go about attaching the outlet to the backsplash. I could have the hole enlarged but it will be cutting it short and it might be too big. Another option I am considering, but I am not sure how to act on, is to put a thin piece of metal on the other side of the backsplash and have the screw act as clamps.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there an easier method?

[image: example]

Comment: Fill the gap at the bottom with plaster to needed hight. Open the top part to where you need it. Turn off power while working.

Comment: This appears to be a new installation. If you had someone come out and measure and cut the backsplash for you, show them this picture and tell them they cut it wrong and will need to redo it. If you DIY'd it, then manassehkatz has a [good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/250401/34147).

Comment: Pull the blue box down. Someone those aren't in there very tight.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple problems here. But basically the solution is either:

- Cut a bigger hole. Add a box extender to get to the front of the backsplash. Install the receptacle.
- Cut a bigger hole. Mount the box so that it is actually in the backsplash hole, with the front at the front of the backsplash.

Which solution you choose will depend on how easy it is to access the box. If you can remove *and replace* the backsplash without a lot of work, I would take it off, cut the bigger hole and then remount the box so that it fits in the backsplash instead of using an extender.

You can get larger-than-normal Decora-style faceplates, so that if the hole is cut a little big and/or ragged, nobody will ever see that.

Comment: I assume the hole needs to be made into a rectangle for the extender to fit in. Would I be missing on something if make the hole large enough and screw it with a long screw without an extender box?

Comment: Two problems: 1 - If there are gaps between the edge of the hole and the box (as currently at the bottom) then that is a code violation - because the stuff (e.g., insulation) could catch fire if there was sparking inside the box; 2 - Anything "except a box" has to itself meet fireproof/resistant standards - that is *likely* not to be an issue here if the backsplash is some sort of stone, but that's the idea of limiting the materials to "known safe".

Comment: NEC 314.20 only allows 1/4" setback for noncombustible surfaces., more than that requires the extender.

Comment: If you can remove and replace the backsplash then it makes more sense to move the box down than to cut the hole larger.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri from what I can see, even if moved down the corners of the hole will need to be squared off for the box to fit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact: Yes, I see what you mean. I wonder what that tile cutter was thinking of.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri when I asked the contractor about it they told me that's not needed and that they do it this way all the time.

Comment: They *obviously* do not "do it this way all the time". What they do all the time looks a lot like this, except that the hole in the backsplash must line up with the junction box.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you had a "professional" do it this way, and you're thinking since a professional did it, it must be right.   Afraid not.

As others have said, Code requires outlets be mounted INSIDE listed junction boxes that is rated to safely contain the kinds of electrical problems that happen inside junction boxes.   The box must come flush to the wall... with one exception, if the  closely surrounding material is known to be fireproof (e.g. drywall, concrete or stone), the box can be up to 1/4" (6mm) short of the wall.

Not 2 inches lol.

##### How I'd attack it.

As manassehkatz says, you will need to enlarge the hole.  To keep the enlarging to an absolute minimum, I would use a 2-pronged attack:

- Use the smallest box available, a metal "Handy-Box". These are available as extender boxes that can stack off the box you have... although if you want extenders of arbitrary thickness, that may be tricky to obtain. Don't waste time at big-box stores, talk to a proper electrical supply house.
- Move the GFCI so it isn't here.  Because GFCIs can't fit inside Handy-Boxes.  (it is extremely difficult at best!) This requires you grasp a huge concept about GFCI protection: **GFCI is not a receptacle!  It is a zone of protection. A GFCI in one location can provide GFCI protection to outlets elsewhere**. So wherever the power to this outlet *comes from*, put the GFCI there.  If it's a breaker, that's fine, they make GFCI breakers.

Comment: It is blessing in disguise. Had they not messed up the hole alignment I would have just used long screws. I got the hole enlarged and I found an off-the-shelf extension box that fits nicely in the new hole and able to hold the GFCI in it.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would put a screw in that bottom hole of the electrical box and measure to the edge of the hole. If that measurement is greater than 5/8" then a standard electrical plate won't work. If it's greater than 7/8" then an oversize plate won't work either. Even if it's greater than 7/8" you may still find a "custom" plate at a design shop that will work. What is on the other side of the wall, can you access the box from the other side to adjust it? What is the backslash made of, some solid surfaces can be patched? In any event I would follow the advice from @manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact as far as getting the box code compliant.

Comment: The standard electrical plate sits 1/8 inches of the stone, I have not figured out yet, but my best guess here is that large size will fit in. I do no have access to it from the other side and it's a backsplash-countertop 3cm. Not something I feel comfortable taking off.